# Vector orthogonal to the set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, orthogonality

Let's suppose that we have $n-1$ vectors $v_1, v_2 ... v_{n-1}$ in $n$-dimensional space.

Now we want to have any non-zero vector $w$ which is orthogonal to all these vectors $v_i$.
If these $n-1$ vectors are linearly independent we have a simple formula for obtaining this vector i.e.
 $ w = det  {\begin{bmatrix}
       e_1 & e_2 & ... & e_n \\
        &v_1^T\\
        &v_2^T \\
&..... \\
&v_{n-1}^T \end{bmatrix}} $

where $e_1, e_2, .. e_n$ are standard basis vectors
(similar formula is used for 3-D cross product - in $2^{nd},3^{rd} .. n^{th}$ row we have as entries of the matrix components of vectors $v_i$ i.e. scalars but in the first row  vectors are entries so the result of calculation of this determinant is a vector).

***Question:***

how to obtain **any** non-zero vector $w$ orthogonal to all vectors $v_i$ in the case when $v_1, v_2 ... v_{n-1}$ are  linearly  dependent or we simply don't know  whether they are or are not linearly independent ?
Can we achieve it with a use of other  single formula ?

Comment: First we want to establish linear independence for the given vectors so that we know what we are dealing with. That's a standard technique. As far as creating an orthogonal vector, that can be done using the dot product. If the vector to be creates is of the form $<a,b,c,d,...>$ then dot this vector with all other vectors and you arrive at a homogeneous system. It's solution is the Null space from which one solution can be obtained for your vector.

Comment: @imranfat   Yes, but  it is a multi-step procedure. Could not by applied something simpler, in a single step preferably ? Please note that not all orthogonal vectors are required but it's enough to have any single vector..

Comment: I am not aware of a simpler method, though with a graphing calculator (matrix tool) it isn't all that hard. Provide an actual example might help

Comment: @imranfat  Could not be the formula with determinant somehow modified for the purpose of finding an orthogonal vector?

Comment: I honestly don't know. I know the method of the cross product for the R3 case and otherwise the dot product for the general case. Never lets me down

Comment: @imranfat  I have not found the formula, so the only way seems to be to use multi-step procedure in the form proposed by you or some variant of it. If you want you can describe it -- it would be as the answer...   at the moment from my point of view multi-step procedure can be described as below: 1. from the given vectors made with Gram-Schmidt process orthonormal basis for a subspace spanned by these vectors 2. attach to them standard basis vectors ( e.g.$ [ 1\ 0\  0 ..]^T, [0\ 1\  0 ..]^T) $and continue GS process for every basis vector separately until you obtain wanted orthogonal vector.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean by formula some expression that is a continuous function of its arguments, then the answer is that this is impossible, for similar reasons to what I explained in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1978269/18880).

Suppose your $n-1$ vectors span a space of dimension $d<n-1$, then the space $S$ of possible vectors orthogonal to them has dimension $n-d>1$. Now if you take any subspace $L$ of dimension$~1$ in $S$, you can easily make that line to be the only set of possibilities by making a very small adjustment to your vectors (add small multiples of vectors in $S$ but orthogonal to $L$ to some of your vectors). By continuity, the vector of $S$ that your formula chooses must be arbitrarily close to any such line $L$, and the zero vector is the only one that satisfies this requirement.

Comment: Yes, this is a very general description. From other questions I know now that basis vectors of $n$-dimensional space could be applied in the process and some of them, for sure, are not belonging to the subspace. Because operation $Ae_i$ is just a choice of the $i^{th}$ column of A  ( we need non-zero vector) the simplest way of finding a required vector it seems to construct  $A$ matrix which should be of the form $I-P$ where $P$ is projection into subspace. Is it a good strategy ?

Comment: Additionally. ..Maybe expression $V(V^TV)^{-1}V^T$ can be also useful ? ( $V$ - matrix where columns are $v_i$) ?